# Base a function arg type on previous arg value

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have 2 types, Hero and Monster

```
interface Hero {
  stat: {
    int: number;
  }
}

interface Monster {
  stat: {
    str: number;
  }
}
```

I want to create a function which returns a path

```
function getFieldPath<T>(fieldA: string, fieldB: string): string {
  return `${fieldA}.${fieldB}`;
}
```

Now with the above definition I can write anything for fieldA and fieldB as long as it's a string. But I want it to be smart and check that the given type T has indeed the key fieldA and the key fieldA[fieldB].

```
getFieldPath<Monster>('stat', 'str'); // Should be fine
getFieldPath<Monster>('stat', 'int'); // Should throw an error
getFieldPath<Hero>('stat', 'str'); // Should throw an error
getFieldPath<Hero>('stat', 'int'); // Should be fine
```

Is that possible? What type should fieldA and fieldB have?

Thanks

EDIT: Added [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/fr/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAMwK4DsDGMCWEVwObAwBimwANgCYAKAhjABYA8AKgHwAUCplAggFxwA1sACeEBHGZwAZHADOMKJhR4ANIm4UAQgOFiJzANp7xkgLoz5i5XgCUAhUpVwA3gCg4cKISRRcAAwASFy5yCh4AXwA6YNDKLQj-AG43CLc3ZRhgKAQaNGA4AGVsgDdsgHVoSlcPTzgyGgAjcgdrFRS6uDz8uTkBd07O7xoKAUM4AHJGhumaCfUpskxpzAm4M1VawbgAdyUsscnZ2fmjpZW1sy24NLS3AmJNWgZGYqgyqEqoSg4J7uBeqcJsMKBNbEkgA)

Comment: This way of using generic parameters is unsafe. Generic parameter should be infered from function argument in 99% cases.

Comment: The function argument does not hold that info. It's just a string. I don't want to be able to type any string in it. By typing thing correctly I can make sure devs write an actual key of the given interface